# Inserting Attribute In JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I am currently looking for a solution to insert align="center" into a block quote. I am hitting an API and getting back a string of HTML as shown:

```
<blockquote class="twitter-tweet"><p lang="en" dir="ltr">Las Vegas utilities really don’t want the strip to go solar blah blah</blockquote>
```

What I am trying to do is add an align="center" to the blockquote in the most efficient way as shown below:

```
<blockquote class="twitter-tweet" align="center"><p lang="en" dir="ltr"></blockquote>
```

I am currently going Rambo and just replacing the string using:

```
myString = myString.replace("<blockquote class=\"twitter-tweet\">", "<blockquote class=\"twitter-tweet\" align=\"center\">");
```

But it feels as if this is a hacky solution as I am fairly new to JavaScript. Is there a better way to do it using JQuery and serializing the HTML that I am missing?

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/attr/?

Comment: Use CSS, via JavaScript: `blockquoteReference.style.textAlign = 'center'`?

Comment: `align="center"` has been deprecated for quite some time now.  Use CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you tell us in your tags, you're somehow using jQuery so why don't do:

```
$("blockquote").attr("align","center");
```

And then use it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ //or in some other function
    $("blockquote").attr("align","center"); 
});
```

I think you know, that you can do this with CSS so I won't tell you again. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You should use css. But if you really want to use the attribute,

`$("blockquote").attr("align","center")`

Answer (score -1):

In the css file, add

```css
blockquote{
text-align:center;
}
```